# How to check whether the given string is boolean or not in Java?

Tags: java, string, boolean

I have one string. I have to verify whether it is of type boolean or not?

The conditions for Boolean are below:

```
{ TRUE,True,true,T,t,YES,Yes,yes,Y,y}
```

and the same for negative case also.

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: I am using in the following way. But it seems to be hard coded. I'm looking for best solution. 
if ("true".equals(map.get(key).toString()) || "TRUE".equals(map.get(key).toString()) || "True".equals(map.get(key).toString()) || "T".equals(map.get(key).toString()) || "t".equals(map.get(key).toString())) 
{ 
System.out.println("Its a Boolan type\n"); 
} 
else 
{ 
System.out.println("It's not a boolean type\n"); 
}

Comment: Check out the  `Boolean.valueOf()` method. [Boolean.valueOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29)
It says: The Boolean returned represents a `true` value if the string argument is not `null` and is equal, ignoring case, to the string "true".

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code there (otherwise it is not formatted in a way that is easy to read).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use String.matches(String)

```
if (map.get(key).matches("(?i)t(rue)?|y(es)?")) {
  // true boolean
} else if (map.get(key).matches("(?i)f(alse)?|n(o)?")) {
  // false boolean
} else {
  // not boolean
}
```

The argument to matches is a regular expression.

(?i) says to ignore case.

the form t(rue)? says just t or true (the rue is optional)

| (bar character) is like saying or

the rest of the words are defined like true

Comment: Like one of the other answers, it also matches `"tRuE"`, but that might be acceptable.  Note: you're missing a couple right parens.... fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Set up a set, once:

```
static final Set<String> trueStrings = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("TRUE", "true", "True", "T", "t", "YES", "Yes", "yes", "Y", "y"));
```

and then, each time you want to test a string:

```
boolean isTrue = trueStrings.contains(yourString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than duplicating your code with

```
"true".equals(map.get(key).toString()) || "TRUE".equals(map.get(key).toString()) || True".equals(map.get(key).toString())
```

your can use the `equalsIgnoreCase` method so it becomes

```
"true".equalsIgnoreCase(map.get(key).toString())
```

Likewise with `t`and `T`

Comment: Except that it also accepts `"tRuE"` and we're not sure the questioner wants that.  In most real-life situations it would be acceptable, though.

Comment: I am sure that the OP does want this.  100% sure that it ;-)